# How to communicate between an Android Broadcast Receiver and a RemoteService

Tags: android, service, broadcastreceiver

I have an Android application that contains a remote service of which I want to use to process data sent via a BroadcastReceiver.

What would be the best way to send data from the BroadcastReceiver to the remote service? My first intention was to Bind using the RemoteServiceConnection, but this is not supported in the BroadcastReceiver. Any assistance is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Still looking for an alternative solution for this problem, any help is greatly appreciated.